# Multiple functions with onPrepare in Protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

I have a `conf.js` file in my Protractor test suite.

There was a single `onPrepare` entry at first but now I wish to add a second.

I'm struggling to get the syntax right so that what follows `onPrepare` is error free.

Original entry:

```
onPrepare: function() {

    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);
  },
```

and the second entry is:

```
const protractorImageComparison = require('protractor-image-comparison');
  browser. protractorImageComparison = new protractorImageComparison(
      {
          baselineFolder: 'path/to/baseline/',
          screenshotPath: 'path/to/save/actual/screenshots/'
      }
    );
  },
}
```

Do I need to add a second `function()` above `const`?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Hi - Errors if you have more than one 'onPrepare' and lots of fun with } , ) and ; with multiple statements beneath a single 'onPrepare'. However @yong's response below seems to work thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try as below? 
A tip: onPrepare is the only one place in protractor conf file you can use the variable: browser, because only when run to this function the browser variable initialize complete.

```
onPrepare: function() {

    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);

    const protractorImageComparison = require('protractor-image-comparison');
    browser.protractorImageComparison = new protractorImageComparison(
      {
          baselineFolder: 'path/to/baseline/',
          screenshotPath: 'path/to/save/actual/screenshots/'
      }
    );
},
```

Comment: Thanks @yong - working well. Thanks for the 'browser' tip too!